# std::visit and std::variant usage

Tags: c++, c++17, std-variant

```cpp
#include <variant>
#include <exception>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cassert>

template <typename T>
struct Promise {
    std::variant<
        std::monostate,
        std::conditional_t<std::is_void_v<T>, std::monostate, T>,
        std::exception_ptr
    > result_;

    T await_resume() const {
        assert(result_.index() > 0);
#if 1
        // old code that I want to optimise
        if (result_.index() == 2) {
            std::rethrow_exception(std::get<2>(result_));
        }
        if constexpr (!std::is_void_v<T>) {
            return std::get<1>(result_);
        }
#else
        // new code, won't compile
        return std::visit([](auto&& arg) {
            using TT = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
            if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<TT, std::exception_ptr>) {
                std::rethrow_exception(arg);
            } else if constexpr (!std::is_void_v<T>) {
                return arg;
            }
        });
#endif
    }
};

template int Promise<int>::await_resume() const;
template std::exception_ptr Promise<std::exception_ptr>::await_resume() const;
template void Promise<void>::await_resume() const;
```

[Promise::await_resume](https://github.com/CarterLi/liburing4cpp/blob/async/promise.hpp#L24) is a simple function which does following thing:

1. If the variant holds a value of `std::exception_ptr`, rethrow the exception.
2. If the variant holds a value of `T` (while T is set by users, may also be std::exception_ptr), return it out. If type of T is void, do nothing.

Originally I implement it using `.index()` check and `std::get`. It works, but `std::get` things generate extra checks internally and `std::__1::__throw_bad_variant_access()` things that not expected to happen: https://godbolt.org/z/YnjxDy

I want to optimise the code using std::visit according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit#Example), but can't get it compile.

Another problem is that when the type of T is std::exception_ptr, how can I know whether I should throw it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`visit` doesn't "optimise" code - it's just a good pattern for matching on the `variant`, and it's especially useful to ensure that you didn't forget any types.

But one of the requirements of `visit` is that each alternative has to return the same type. This is especially problematic in your use case, since only one of your alternatives should be returned... so it's just not a good fit. You also *need* to handle the `monostate` case in the `visit`, and you really have no way to do that (besides... throwing?) so you're just out of luck.

The version you had before is perfectly fine, I would just annotate it with types a bit to be more expressive:

```
struct Void { };

template <typename T>
struct Promise {
    using Value = std::conditional_t<std::is_void_v<T>, Void, T>;

    std::variant<
        std::monostate,
        Value,
        std::exception_ptr
    > result_;

    T await_resume() const {
        assert(not result_.valueless_by_exception());
        assert(not std::holds_alternative<std::monostate>(result_));

        if (auto* exc = std::get_if<std::exception_ptr>(&result)) {
            std::rethrow_exception(*exc);
        } else {
            if constexpr (not std::is_void_v<T>) {
                return std::get<T>(result_);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think this is just a bit nicer than using `0`, `1`, and `2` explicitly.

---

> Another problem is that when the type of `T` is `std::exception_ptr`, how can I know whether I should throw it?

Simple: You don't throw it. Don't have wildly different semantics in generic code based on your type. `Promise<T>::await_resume()` returns a `T` if it holds a `T`. `Promise<std::exception_ptr>::await_resume()` returns an `exception_ptr`. That's fine.

I guess actually with my implementation above, using the explicit `get_if<exception_ptr>` would become ambiguous, which is unfortunate... so maybe the `0`/`1`/`2` is just the easy way to go.

Comment: Does `std::variant` have methods that behaves as get_or_ub_if_mismatched like what std::vector::operator[] does?

Comment: > But one of the requirements of visit is that each alternative has to return the same type.

I can make them return the same type. Just write `return T()` after `rethrow_exception`. Since `rethrow_exception` is declared as `no_return`, code after `rethrow_exception` should not generate any code. But it still won't compile.

Comment: @CarterLi 1) No. 2) `return T();` only helps if your type is default constructible, and also `arg`  could be a `T` or a `monostate` so that's still different types.

Comment: 1) It seems that `*get_if<T>(&variant)` does what I want. Because dereferencing a nullptr is UB, compiler removes the code path returning nullptr, including the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Refers to @Barry's answer, this is my final version:

```cpp
T await_resume() const {
    if (auto* pep = std::get_if<2>(&result_)) {
        std::rethrow_exception(*pep);
    } else {
        if constexpr (!std::is_void_v<T>) {
            auto* pv = std::get_if<1>(&result_);
            assert(pv);
            return *pv;
        }
    }
}
```

Generates perfect asm, no extra checks, no bad_variant_access sh*t: https://godbolt.org/z/96gF_J